# In C++, when I pass a value into a function, is it always converted to appropiate type?

Tags: c++, function, types, type-conversion, literals

If I have a function like `void func(size_t x)` and I call the function `func(5)`, is 5 immediately converted to `size_t` type? Does this hold generally for all types?

I ask because I swear I've seen people write code where they do stuff like `func(5.0)` (passing 5 as a double) or `func(0UL)` (passing 0 as an unsigned long int). Is this really necessary? Can't we just pass in whatever we want, and C++ will treat it as the type that I used to define the function?

Comment: ***Does this hold generally for all types?*** No, not all types are convertible. In that case you will get an error. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: "Prefer explicit to implicit" - I can't quite remember who. Anybody can help?

Comment: @Fureeish You might be thinking of [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Justin strongly doubt that. I think I heard it once during a Scott Meyers' lectures, but I can't tell for sure

Comment: "Can't we just pass in whatever we want, and C++ will treat it as the type that I used to define the function?" Yes, if there is a conversion  - but the conversion might not be what you want (C++ and C conversion rules are quite complicated), or there might not be a conversion.

Comment: This is to be sure that the expected overload is called.

Comment: There are just an ungodly number of rules for converting between the builtin types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 6):

If there is an implicit conversion between the argument type and the type passed to the function then the argument will be converted.  If there isn't one, like trying to pass a `std::list` to a function that expects a `std::vector` then it won't and you will get an error.

One reason to use a specific literal, like `func(5.0)` or `func(5UL)` is if `func` is a template function, or is overloaded.  If `func` is a template or is overloaded (for the appropriate types) then `func(5.0)`, `func(5UL)` and `func(5)` would generate/call 3 different functions.  One for a `double`, one for a `unsigned long` and one for an `int`.  This could be meaningful as there could be specializations/overloads handling these types differently.

You also run into cases like `std::accumulate` whose third parameter, the accumulator, has its own template type.  Lets say you want to sum all of the elements in a `std::vector<double>`.  If you use

```
std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0)
```

then you would get a different result than

```
std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0.0)
```

because the first call uses an `int` to store the sum which will truncate each time, while the latter uses a `double` and you will get the expected result.

Comment: _then you would get a different result than_... Really? yuk.