# Problems referencing one past last element on std::vector<> using operator[]

Tags: c++

Given this valid C or C++ code

```
int x() {
    int numbers[3]; // Lets suppose numbers are filled in with values
    int sum = 0;
    for (const int* p = &numbers[0]; p != &numbers[3]; ++p)
        sum += *p;
    return sum;
}
```

This code uses pointer arithmetic and as far as I know it is valid to have a pointer point to the one past last element inside an array, referencing that pointer is unspecified, but we can have a pointer point to that position.
So, &p[0], &p[1], &p[2] and &p[3] are valid pointers, and p[0], p[1] and p[2] are valid values.

If I replace the int array with a `std::vector<int>` everything should be fine, we get this code

```
#include <vector>
int x() {
    std::vector<int> numbers(3);
    int sum = 0;
    for (const int* p = &numbers[0]; p != &numbers[3]; ++p)
        sum += *p;
    return sum;
}
```

But running under Visual C++ 2017 in DEBUG mode I get this exception "vector subscript out of range", that is triggered from MS STL library because the implementation assumes that using operator[] we are automatically referencing the underlaying value, which is not the case.
This is MS STL code that do the bounds check...

```
    _NODISCARD _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos)
        {   // subscript mutable sequence
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (size() <= _Pos)
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
            }
 #elif _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 1
        _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size());
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL */

        return (this->_Myfirst()[_Pos]);
        }
```

I don´t get the error if I replace &numbers[0] and &numbers[3] with numbers.begin() and numbers.end().

**I agree this is really ugly code, but I simplify the real code just to expose the bug.**

The original code was using &vec[0] on a vector with zero elements.

So my question is:

**Is this a BUG on Microsoft Visual C++ STL implementation or there is some restriction on operator[] for vectors<>?**

I know that replacing [] by at() would be a bug, but I understand &vec[size] should still be valid for std::vector<>

Comment: I don't believe `&p[3]` is a valid pointer, because `p[3]` is invalid to start with.  `p+3` is a valid pointer, that points to the intended location though, as is `vec.begin()+3`

Comment: This is MSVS being "helpful".  Compile in release mode if you don't want debugging support.

Comment: Also, FWIW, the standard way to do this is `auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(container_name), std::end(container_name), container_name::value_type{});`

Comment: @NathanOliver i'd be tempted to use `0` and not `container_name::value_type{}`

Comment: @Caleth It is tempting but it can lead to some [major surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450363/in-c-when-i-pass-a-value-into-a-function-is-it-always-converted-to-appropiat/52450485#52450485) (see bottom half of the answer)

Comment: @NathanOliver yours fails for `int[]`, mine fails for `vector<double>`. If only there were something that worked for both

Comment: @Caleth Yeah.  When I wrote it I was thinking to myself, it would be nice to have a `std::value_type` type trait that would give use the type for containers or arrays.  Generic programing FTW.

Comment: @Caleth: Even worse with `char` and integral promotion.

Answer (score 4):

It has been a grey area whether obtaining a pointer to the one past the last element with `&p[n]` is well defined.

However, a pointer to the one past the last element is well defined.

You can avoid such errors by using plain pointers arithmetic:

```
for (const int* p = numbers.data(); p != numbers.data() + 3; ++p)
```

Or, more generically, iterators:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
for(auto p = begin(v), q = end(v); p != q; ++p)
```

Or using a *range for* loop:

```
for(auto const& element : v)
```

---

There is no good reason to use `v[v.size()]`, really.

Comment: you also can use iterators which in this situation is the same as raw pointers

Comment: I know, but I want to know if thi is a bug on vector<> implementation or not, just being curious.

Comment: Both client and library code is Microsoft property, I only want to know wich one is wrong about this!

Comment: @RicardoCapurro It is highly unlikely that it is a bug in Microsoft standard library in this very popular class.

Comment: I am pretty sure dereferencing *one past the end* is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Galik The pointer to one past the last element is valid, whereas dereferencing it is undefined behaviour. Do not compound these two.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin When you do `[3]` you dereference it. It is valid but not dereferencable.

Comment: @Galik This has been controversial since merely doing `p[index]` does not result in load/store of a value from `p[index]`, so that does not constitute accessing the element yet. Neither does `&p[index]`, unless `Element::operator&` is overloaded.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I can't find where the standard mentions `load`/`store` operations in respect of `[]`. However the `C++17` standard does say that *indirection* through an invalid pointer is `UB` (6.4.7) and that the `unary * operator` performs indirection (8.3.1.1) and that the `a[b]` operation is identical to `*(a + b)` (11.3.4.6).

Answer (score 3):

The debug iterators library in Visual C++ is correctly reporting the problem, and the problem isn't subtle.

According to the standard, [sequence.reqmts] Table 101, the expression `a[n]` for a sequence container `a` of a type providing `operator[]` (`std::vector` does, as does `basic_string`, `deque`, and `array`), has the operational semantics of `*(a.begin()+n)`. However, in the case you're running, `a.begin()+n` will be equivalent to `a.end()`. Therefore, the result is `*(a.end())` *before* applying the address-of operator.

Dereferencing the `end()` iterator of a container invokes *undefined behavior*. Visual C++ is correct in reporting the assertion, and you would do well to change your enumeration strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a past-last element results in undefined behaviour. If you declare `std::vector<int> numbers(3)` then the last element you are allowed to access is `numbers[2]`. Same story with raw arrays.

Avoid using raw arrays if you can:

```
int x() {
    std::vector<int> numbers(3); 
    //...
    int sum = 0;

    for (auto value : numbers)
        sum += value;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Using &numbers[3] is valid on raw arrays, since you are not accessing the element, only the pointer.I suspect it is also valid for std::vector<>.

Comment: @RicardoCapurro According to the standard `numbers[3]` is the same as `*(numbers + 3)` (11.3.4.6) and `*` on a pointer dereferences the object (8.3.1.1).

Comment: Where in the code you are accessing numbers[3]? numbers[3] is not the same as &numbers[3] ...

Comment: It is the same. The C++ standard and the operator precedence table say you're wrong so stop arguing.

Answer (score 1):

> So, &p[0], &p[1], &p[2] and &p[3] are valid pointers

**No.** The subscript operator (`p[x]`) for arrays is syntactic sugar for `*(p+x)`, so `&p[3]` is actually doing `&(*(p+3))` but `*(p+3)` is undefined behavior!!

If all you want is the address of one past last, `p+3` is perfectly valid. This will use pointer arithmetic and not dereference anything.

> If I replace the int array with a std::vector everything should be fine

Again, no! If you try to dereference a memory location you haven't allocated, you *will* get undefined behavior. `std::vector` says nothing about `v[v.length()]` being allocated for you, so this is undefined behavior.

> the implementation asumes that using operator[] we are automatically referencing the underlaying value, wich is not the case

*Yes it is!!* Read [the cppreference page on `operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at): "*Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.*" Just like with the raw arrays, the subscript operator here returns a reference to the underlying value, meaning there's a dereference step involved here!

Comment: `p+9999` is not valid, pedantically.

Comment: @Jarod42 added some clarification on what I mean by "valid"

Comment: No, it is not valid to have a pointer point to p[9999] for a int p[3] array.

Comment: `p+9999` is an expression that produces an invalid pointer. You can't do *anything* with that value

Comment: @Jarod42 is `x = p + 9999; std::cout << x[-9998];` not well defined?

Comment: Even if `*(p+3)` has UB, doesn't mean that `&(*(p+3))` necessarily has UB (assuming `p` is a pointer). There is a standard issue about this (concerning one past last, and null pointer) and there is proposed wording to make those two cases explicitly well defined, but that has not been adopted yet unfortunately (as far as I know).

Comment: &p[9999] is unspecified, it may work with any compiler, but it is unspecified acording to the standard and not portable code.

Comment: Terminology wise `p + 3` is **valid** but not dereferencable. `p + 4` is not valid. But I don't think it is UB either.

Comment: @user2079303 I can't find it at the moment, but doesn't the standard say something about any part of the program having UB makes the whole program UB? So if `*(p+3)` is UB then the very existence of that statement anywhere in the program disqualifies the whole thing?

Comment: In practice `p + 9999` might overflow, and pointer overflow is not defined.

Comment: @RicardoCapurro please reread my answer about the difference between `&p[x]` and `p+x`. One is dereferencing and causing undefined behavior. The other is only pointer arithmetic

Comment: @Jarod42 fair enough. Could the same be said of `p+3` then or is one past last special?

Comment: @user2079303 no, `*(p+3)` being UB really does mean `&(*(p+3))` is UB, by the standard. A particular implementation *may* document a particular behaviour in either case, which is perfectly allowable.

Comment: One past last has special treatment. (also the case for `&var + 1` (treating variable as "array of 1 element")).

Comment: @All I've edited out the `p+9999` part as I agree it could be UB due to overflow on the arithmetic. Thanks for all of the great input here!

Comment: @Caleth It may be the case that `&(*(p+3))` is UB in the standard as it is written (I make no claim either way), but that does not necessarily need to follow from `*(p+3)` being UB. Whether `&(*(p+3))` *should* be UB is another matter, and in my opinion, it shouldn't be if only for compatibility with C where it unambiguously isn't UB.

Comment: @user2079303 `*` is used to *dereference* a pointer. One past the end pointers are **not** dereferenceable.